# Tomcat - Doesn't recognize ${}

Tags: tomcat

I've been developing a small app at home, everything working fine. When i decided to upload my app to my host to see it running, i got this problem, in every place i use ${} (like ${context.root}, etc.) it shows as a normal string and most of my app got broken. What can be the problem so i get it fixed?

EDIT: I'm using Spring MVC for this app, its a very simple one just for test purposes, just save and view data from the db. This is the first page with a simple link to another page using ${context.root} to set the base url. Heres the code from the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Mah oeeee!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Alunos!</h1>

    <a href="${context.root}/SGE/aluno/cadastro">Novo aluno</a>
</body>
```

The thing is, instead of showing for ex.: `http://localhost:8080/SGE/aluno/cadastro` on the link, it shows `http://localhost:8080/SGE/${context.root}/SGE/aluno/cadastro`. Same thing happens on the view page, that shows the data from de database:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CONSULTA</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>${aluno.nome}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CPF</td>
            <td>${aluno.cpf}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-Mail</td>
            <td>${aluno.email}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Instead of showing the value of the variables, ex.:

```
Nome:     Joao
CPF:      98765482312
E-mail:   joao@joao.com
```

it just shows like this:

```
Nome    ${aluno.nome}
CPF         ${aluno.cpf}
E-Mail  ${aluno.email}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it shows as a normal string"?  Does that mean that the ${context.root} is replaced with some string XXX ? What is that string XXX ?

Comment: instead of replacing it with the context root, it shows ${context.root} on my links, like www.mydomain.com:8080/mypage/${context.root}/otherpage =/

Comment: Please post the name of the file where this is used, and please cut-and-paste the exact code from that file.

Comment: On my search page, search.jsp i have this link to add a new student: <a href="${context.root}/sglim/alunos/novo">Novo Aluno</a> that show this link: http://gtimotheo.com:8080/sglim/$%7Bcontext.root%7D/sglim/alunos/novo

Answer (score 0):

You need to answer many many questions before you get a helpful answer
Start by answering these
1. Is context.root defined in some property or are you using some framework which understands the property, for ex velocity, etc?
2. You didnt tell where you are using your ${}'s - jsps, properties, xmls?
3. Did you check if your property files if any containing those property definitions are deployed and are available in classpath to your application?

Comment: the context root is provided by spring mvc, also in my login page i use ${not empty login_error ? SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME : ''} in my username input tag, wich also shows as a string in my username field, every page i use ${} to show objects sent from my mapping method show it like ${student.name} as if it were a string

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somewhere, something is re-defining the original symbols.  For example, something is saying

student.name="${student.name}"

and

context.root="${context.root}"

Take a hard look at the config files.  Post snippets of them here if the cause is not apparent. In particular, take a look at the Context tag in server.xml, or definitions in other xml files that define the context or paths.